# How do I convert this statement to implication? Or is it not possible?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$\neg P \land \neg Q \land \neg R$$

The implication may have negations, but no or/and

Comment: No, that simply not equivalent to **any** "implication" statement.  It is, however, equivalent to "not (P **or** Q **or** R)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Note that $S\lor T$ is equivalent to $\neg(\neg S)\lor T$, which in turn is equivalent to $\neg S\to T$. We can apply De Morgan’s law to see that $\neg P\land\neg Q\land\neg R$ is equivalent to $\neg(P\lor Q\lor R)$. Using the first observation, we see that this is equivalent to $\neg\big(\neg P\to(Q\lor R)\big)$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: $\neg\big(\neg P\to(Q\lor R)\big)$.

Comment: @KracX: You still need to get rid of that OR.

Comment: By transitivity of equivalence, we see from Brian's answer that $S \vee T$ is equivalent to $\neg S \rightarrow T$. That's what gets rid of the "or".

Comment: would it become 
$\neg P \to (\neg Q \to R)$

Comment: @KracX: Yes, exactly. You get rid of the second OR using the same trick that got rid of the first.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Originally my question was: heres a venn diagram, find the regions that are True, and construct a implication that illustrates this... so for that, do i just find all the regions, stick a "or" between them, and simplify like we did here?

Comment: @KracX: Depending on the diagram there may be quicker approaches, but that would certainly be one systematic way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
\neg P \land \neg Q \land \neg R
&= \neg P \land \neg (Q \lor  R)\\
&= \neg P \land \neg (\neg Q \Rightarrow R) \\
&= \neg (P \lor (\neg Q \Rightarrow R))\\
&= \neg (\neg P \Rightarrow (\neg Q \Rightarrow R)))\\
&= \neg (\neg P \Rightarrow (\neg Q \Rightarrow R)))\\
\end{align}

You might want to look up [Karnuagh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) also